# show that $Q(z)=1/2\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}(-1)^k\overline{p}_{1-k}z^{k}$

Tags: wavelets

Let $P(z)=\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}p_{k}z^{k}$ and define $Q(z)=-z\overline{p(-z)}$.
for $\left | z \right |=1$, show that 
$Q(z)=1/2\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}(-1)^k\overline{p}_{1-k}z^{k}$.

Comment: Please? And what are the $\;p_k$'s ? And what have **you** done so far to tackle this problem?

Comment: For some finite number of constants $p_{k}$

Comment: ....and? What did you try? For example, you have that $\;1=|z|=|z|^2=z\,\overline z\iff \overline z=\frac1z\;$ and etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that

$$|z|=1\iff 1=|z|^2=z\overline z\iff z=\frac1{\overline z}$$

$$Q(z)=-z\overline{p(-z)}=-z\overline{\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}p_k(-z)^k}=-z\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}\overline{p_k}\overline{(-z)^k}=-\overline{z^{-1}}\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}\overline{p_k}\overline{(-z)^k}=$$

$$=\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}\overline{p_k}\overline{(-z)^{k-1}}=\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}(-1)^{k-1}\,\overline{p_k}\,\overline{z^{k-1}}$$

Now finish the problem.

Comment: Thanks Timbuc but $Q(z)=1/2\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}(-1)^k\overline{p}_{1-k}z^{k}$ and Your result is different ?

Comment: @ehsanzarei There is no "result" in my answer: you still have some work to do (very little, btw.). I showed you my way, now you complete.